# C++ Function pointer to member function of a static pointer object

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a class (B) which has a static member pointer to an object of another class (A). In one member function of the first class (B), I need a function pointer that points to a member function of the second class (A).

```
class A
{
public:
    int DoubleValue(int nValue)
    {
        return nValue * 2;
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    static A* s_pcA;
public:
    void Something()
    {
        // Here a need the function pointer to s_pcA->DoubleValue()
    }
};
```

I have tried this:

```
int (*fpDoubleValue) (int nValue) = s_pcA->DoubleValue;
```

But Xcode says *"Reference to non-static member function must be called"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot obtain pointer to a member function of a class instance. Instead, you need to create a function object that contains pointer to a class instance and to a member function. You can use `std::bind` for that purpose:

```
auto fpDoubleValue = std::bind (&A::DoubleValue, s_pcA , std::placeholders::_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function also can be used:

```
auto fpDoubleValue = [](int nValue) { return s_pcA->DoubleValue(nValue); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a pointer on method:

```
int (A::*fpDoubleValue) (int nValue) = &A::DoubleValue;
```

or in your case make the method static since it doesn't depend of `this`:

```
class A
{
public:
    static int DoubleValue(int nValue) { return nValue * 2; }
};
```

then

```
int (*fpDoubleValue) (int nValue) = &A::DoubleValue;
```